# Having trouble with recursion

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program which prints all the possible permutations of the string "A?B?AB?" via replacing question marks with A or B. I can't understand why my code works the way it does and need help improving it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* rec(char s[8]){
    int i=0;
    for(;i<strlen(s);i++){
    if(s[i]=='?'){
        s[i]='A';
        rec(s);
        s[i]='B';
        rec(s);
        s[i]='?';
    }
    }
    for(int k=0;k<strlen(s);k++){
        if(s[k]=='?')
            i=-1;
    }
        if(i!=-1)
            printf("%s\n",s);

    return s;
}

int main(){
    char s[8]="A?B?AB?";
    rec(s);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should take some time to learn how to use a *debugger* to be able to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: You probably want to read this: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471) You may also want to read this: [How to debug small programs?](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Do you have a specific problem or a question in mind? Or do you need help understanding recursion in general? Please take look at the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for what you need to include in your question. It will help us to help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void rec(char *str, int size, int depth){
    for (int i = depth; i < size; i++){
        if (str[i] == '?'){
            str[i] = 'A';
            rec(str, size, i + 1);

            str[i] = 'B';
            rec(str, size, i + 1);

            str[i] = '?';
            return;
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", str);
}

int main(){
    char s[8] = "A?B?AB?";
    rec(s, strlen(s), 0);
}
```

It's much like August's solution, but I did decide to do some looping until it found the next question mark. That should avoid having too big of a callstack, which could lead to stack overflow, with really big strings. (Note: I didn't test it, so there could still be some minor problems)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to look at one character at a time. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PrintPermutationsFrom(int i, char s[])
{
    if (s[i] == '?') {
        s[i] = 'A';
        PrintPermutationsFrom(i + 1, s);
        s[i] = 'B';
        PrintPermutationsFrom(i + 1, s);
        s[i] = '?';
    } else if (s[i] != '\0') {
        PrintPermutationsFrom(i + 1, s);
    } else {
        puts(s);
    }
}


void PrintPermutations(char s[])
{
    PrintPermutationsFrom(0, s);
}


int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "A?B?AB?";

    PrintPermutations(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> I can't understand why my code works the way it does and need help improving it.

The `rec` code does simply too much in that after having replaced a `?` with both `A` and `B` and called itself, it continues iterating over `s` and generates further output. That is too much because after the first found `?`, the recursive invocations already have handled all following `?` and generated all arrangements. To correct this, just insert a `break;` after `s[i]='?';`.